# Attach database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I installed SQL Server 2008 Express on my PC and then wanted to attach my database (both of my database files are in full control accessibility).

The attach operation failed and shows this error:

[image]

Comment: Please describe how exactly are you attaching the database. Expand the error message to show details.

Comment: What's the actual error message? That box just directs you to the real problem, look at it first.